# How to add a static function declaration with "Quick actions and refactorings" in VS 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, refactoring

I really like this new feature in VS 2017 with exception of one little nuance. Let me explain:

- Type in some new function declaration in a `.cpp` file, say:

  ```
  int CTestMfc2017Dlg::MyStaticFunction(int input)
  {
  }
  ```
- Then right-click its name and select `Quick actions and refactorings` and pick `Create declaration/definition`:

  [image]
- VS 2017 will add its declaration into the class as its member function in the `.h` file.

But, is it possible to use this feature to add a `static` function to a class?

Comment: Maybe you can do it other way around: create declaration of static function in header file and then add definition?

Comment: @VTT: Well, I've been doing it like I showed above since day one of using VS. Old habits die hard, you know.